# Complete a total ordered abstract set

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Given a total ordered abstract set $(S,\preceq)$. The set is said to be complete if any non-empty  subset that is bounded from above/below has a supremum/infimum.

Given a $(S,\preceq)$ may not be complete, could we always complete it in certain ways?

To be specific, I am considering the set of Hardy's L-functions which are eventually non-negative, and $f\preceq g$ iff $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq 1$. I need to either prove this total ordered set is complete, or show that it can be complete.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what sort of answers you're looking for. Are you looking for completely abstract order-theoretic results? EG [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion)?

Comment: Thanks very much Izaak. My question arises from the total ordered set mentioned above. But now I am finding an abstract order-theoretic result. The Dedekind-MacNeille completion is super helpful. Though it doesn't give an infimum as a growing function, it seems to be sufficient for me to state a theoretic result.